# If text() equal do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, the title of question look like easy, and the solution is:

```
$('.weatherCity').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'LONDON') {
        $(this).text('London Weather');
    }
});
```

but I working on `Yahoo! Weather Plugin` and want to change city name, it's not `iframe` and we allow to change `style` and etc.. but look like it won't let change any text in this plugin. I thought browser read my code then yahoo get the weathers then I used `promise().done()` but nothing changed.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/7qvJH/191/)**

*Thanks in advance*

*-jiff*

Comment: The issue you have is that the elements containing the location text are appended to the DOM dynamically, so running your code on load of the page has no effect. You need to run it when the plugin loads, however the plugin does not raise any events, so I don't believe this is possible. You could use `setTimeout()` but that would be very unreliable and not good practice. The plugin itself is discontinued according to its own website, have you searched for an alternative which does what you require?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I searched and it's best for my work, i knew it's discontinued but still works. and the funny thing is `down vote` ! look like people like to push down vote to every question that they can not solve! , I got my answer with your reply, I wanted to know it's possible or not. don't understand why they give `down vote`  anyway. thanks for reply

Comment: Instead of timeout, you could use mutation observer to detect when plugin has added content or even using some CSS transition event (hacky)

Comment: Well, many downvotes, i'm just guessing why???

Comment: can you explain more about ` mutation observer` I didn't hear before. @A.Wolff

Comment: Sometimes when they see just one `down vote` they going to push `down vote` for fun , it doesn't matter. @A.Wolff

Comment: @jiff did you check my answer? I think it will meet your requirement.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes, I voted, still waiting for another solution to accept. but looke like it's first and last solution for me. I'll accept.

Comment: @jiff See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qvJH/194/) using [MutationObserver](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around for this problem, you can use like this,

```
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('.weatherCity').length) {
     $('.weatherCity').each(function() {
       if ($(this).text().trim() == 'London') {
         $(this).text('London Weather');
       }
     });
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
 }, 100);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qvJH/192/)

Constantly checks for the element using `setInterval` and stop checking once it is found.